combinations where at least m elements are different?
Starting from the well known $N$ choose $K$ formula, it gives us the total number of combinations where at least one element is different between any two combinations. My question is whether this concept can be generalized such that we can calculate the total number of combinations where at least m elements are different between any two combinations.
A little illustration.
$5$ choose $3$ gives us $10$ combinations where at least $1$ element is different, namely:
$$\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,4\}, \{1,2,5\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{1,3,5\}, \{1,4,5\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{2,3,5\}, \{2,4,5\}, \{3,4,5\}$$
This can easily be calculated from the formula for $N$ choose $K$:
$$\binom{N}{K} = \dfrac{N!}{((N-K)! \cdot K!)}$$
Now, if we want all combinations where at least two elements are different, only $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,4,5\}$ would survive.
Is there a formula or way to calculate this for the general case $N$ choose $K$ where at least $m$ elements are different between any two combinations?

You need to specify your question further.  The examples you picked are very specific and it is unclear how to generalize...
When you say 'only (1,2,3) and (2,4,5) would survive' that seems rather arbitrary, as (1,4,5) and (2,3,5) would also differ in two elements for example. The binomial counts the number of possible subsets of size k of a set of size n, and it is unclear what generalized concept you would like to count.

I don't understand what you are counting.  $\binom NK$ counts the number of ways to choose $K$ distinct elements from $N$ objects.  What is it you meant to count?   What is special about ${1,2,3}$ or ${2,4,5}$?  They look like ordinary selections.

My guess: you want the size of a maximal collection of subsets of the given size such that the intersection of any two doesn't exceed a fixed size.  Is that right?  It's only a guess.

I have a set of 2000 elements, and I want to know roughly or exactly the total number of subsets of 100 elements where these subsets are largely different. If I use 2000 choose 100, I will get many combinations that differ only by a few elements. But I want combinations that are different by at least 50 elements or more. Maybe this is an ill posed problem mathematically, but then some guidance on how to make it well posed would also be helpful.
